# Why does Webkit browsers add extra space on the right of my text?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I am currently working on a small project, and have managed to find myself puzzled on some weird bug that only seems to appear on desktop webkit-browsers.

I have a menu in my header which is supposed to look like this: <sup>(I can't embed images or multiple links normally in my post yet, sadly)</sup>

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lspNK.png
```

This is the exact result I'm getting in any non-webkit browser. However, if I open it in Google Chrome or Opera, I get this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz3Pp.png
```

I've tried nearly anything possible to figure out why this is happening, but have come up blank every time. I've checked for unwanted `margin` on my `<a>` anchors and the padding I've added is supposed to be even (`1.2em`) on both sides. I even tried re-writing every little piece of `HTML` and `CSS` for the menu, but to no avail.

Then I happened to try and highlight the entire page and saw this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOdLG.png
```

It looks like the extra space next to the text is a percent-width of the actual word, so I figured maybe it was the font (`'Oswald'` from Google fonts) I was using. I tried changing `font-family:` to `Arial` and the bug was gone.

Now, to return to my original question: ***Why does this extra space get added in webkit browsers?*** Does it have to do with Webkit's font rendering or have I screwed up somewhere?

You should be able to see a live test version of the site I'm building here:

http://bbg.gnifle.com/

If the bug doesn't occur immidiately, try refreshing a few times. - Let me know if any further details can help and I'll try and provide!

**Note:** Using Chrome developer tools to change any CSS property seems to remove this weird space - I have no idea why, but the bug still persists after refreshing!

Comment: Define your anchor tag this css .header-content nav > ul > li > a{display:block;}

Comment: @RohitAzad Pardon me, it is supposed to be 'display: block'. I was playing around with it to see what would happen. I changed it - try refreshing, bug still occurs! Note that changing anything in the developer tols seems to actually fix the bug for some reason - another thing I can't seem to explain!

Comment: i'ven't seen nothing that go wrong, except the ".page { background: linear-gradient(#263B4E, #2A2E31)}" not supported in Safari PC.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Hmm, that's definitely something I need to look into. I didn't even know there were still people using Safari on PC since I thought it was scrapped. I found an older version of Safari PC and you're right, the bug doesn't seem to occur in there. Strange...